# Ruby rspec test command: could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec2

I just installed Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7 and I also installed rubygems. I'm trying to work with rspec so I ran: 
gem install rspec

It seemed to work well and everything installed. SO I went on to try the example on [this](http://rspec.info/) page. But anytime I run the rspec command I get this error message:

"Could not locate Gemfile".

According to the example, I should get: "./bowling_spec.rb:4:
  uninitialized constant Bowling"

I've googled it and it was suggested I try bundle exec rspec but it still yielded the same results. 
I have also tried the suggestion on [this](https://gist.github.com/1446944) page but it yields the same results. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the Gemfile with this content. Gemfile can have no extension or .gem extension

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec'
```

so you have

```
app/
  Gemfile or Gemfile.gem
  spec/
    bowling_spec.rb
```

Also you might need to execute this commands after

```
gem install bundler
```

and then, in the app directory

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Hi what extension do I save the gem file with? Also where do I find this app/spec directory you are referring to? I just created an rspec_tutorial folder to store these test files. Thanks

Comment: Gemfile has no extension. What I refer to app directory is the one you are testing. So in your case could be the app rspec_tutorial and you should place your spec files in a spec directory so rspec knows where to get them. It's not necessary but in real projects you will do this. Also I think it should be specs directory instead of spec. Sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks but I'm still confused as to how the gem file has no extension? Should I just save as a txt file then? And when I tried bundle install command it still says cannot find gemfile

Comment: hm. I never worked in Ruby in Windows but if you cannot create files without any extension (even with a code texteditor?) try to use .GEM extension

Comment: Ok I just did that. I saved it as GemFile.gem and saved it in the spec folder inside the rspec_tutorial directory along with the bowling_spec.rb file. Still the same error message cannot find GemFile

Comment: No, the gemfile must be in the app directory, not inside the spec

Answer (score 1):

gem install rspec in the same directory as your app and
change require statement to require './bowling.rb'

Comment: Thanks for response but it still didn't work

*edit*. I deleted the rspec.cmd file from path variable and it worked this time. But I thought the idea of the tutorial in the link was for the require code to be wrong so it would give the required error message? The problem is when I do that, I get loads of confusing errors messages, not just one :(

Comment: Tried it all over again, still cannot locate gemfile